# Is std::polar thread safe?

Tags: c++, pragma

Is the function `std::polar()` thread safe?

I would like to call the `#pragma` directive on a for that uses it inside.

Comment: The standard doesn't specify if it's thread-safe or not, but I can't imagine an implementation where it's not. Sounds like you're using OpenMP -- consider using something better integrated with C++, like Intel TBB.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is an school project, so I have to stick with it. Anyway, is always good to know other options.
Sincerely,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `std::polar` is thread-safe (for some definition of thread-safe). See `[res.on.data.races]/3`:

> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non- const arguments, including this.

Since `std::polar` only takes const parameters, it does not modify any objects outside the thread that it is called from.